# Rails - Passing a collection to the layout for will_paginate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins, will-paginate

I have my `<%= will_paginate %>` code block in the layout of my application. I'd like to pass this block different collections depending on what controller/action I'm in. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ... rereading your question I see what you mean.

I think the easiest way to do this would simply to always use the same variable name, or to set a standard name with the value from your pagination query.

```
# Controller
@collection = Model.paginate

#OR
@entries = Entry.paginate
@collection = @entries


# View:
<%= will_paginate @collection %>
```

Comment: I didn't want to do it this way, but I guess it'll have to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a collection after the will_paginate method.

In your controller:

```
@collection = MyTable.find(:all, :page => params[:page])
```

In your view:

```
<%= will_paginate @collection %>
```

Comment: Right, but is there a way to pass dynamic collection names to will_paginate? Similar to... render :partial, :locals => { :collection => @dynamic_collection }, then in the layout... <%= will_paginate @collection %> ?

Comment: will_paginate doesn't care about the collection name - it's a variable that conforms to the will_paginate collection behaviour.